# Historic followers_count information for Instagram business account

Tags: facebook-graph-api, instagram, facebook-insights

I'd like to obtain the change in followers over time for an Instagram business account I own.

What I can request from the API is a `followers_count` ([lifetime](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-api/reference/user)) on the user, and a `follower_count` (per [day](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-api/reference/user/insights)) on the user/insights node.

`followers_count` only provides information on the current amount of followers and `follower_count` only provides data on new followers, not on  unfollows.

For Facebook pages I can do: `/insights/?metric=page_fans&since=[some-date]&until=[some-date]`.

How do existing social media apps deal with this?
Iqonosquare, for example, even provides a follower growth example on their [homepage](https://pro.iconosquare.com/).

Am I missing something? Are all these apps constantly scraping the latest followers information for all Instagram business accounts?
Thanks!

Comment: Get `followers_count` once a day, and calculate the difference to the previous day’s value …?

Comment: That would work, but that way I can't get any data from before I started tracking it. (also, if I accidentally lose any information it's lost forever)

Comment: sorry for the misinterpretion, i had to delete my answer because it was about the page insights, not the instagram insights.